# Excel VBA run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error, not sure why it is failing

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel VBA and this is a program used to check for duplicates and paste the data back to the original sheet. I didn't write the coding (it was an intern who is no longer working for us). The run time error happens at this point but all the ranges seem to be defined so I am not sure how to fix this issue? I have a basic idea of VBA but this one I am unable to solve

```
Sub transfterDealColResults()

    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheets("test").Cells(1, 12) = "Colour Name" Then
        Sheets("test").Columns("L").Delete
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim oldLastRow As Long
    Dim lastDRS As Long
    Dim newRowStart As Long
    
    oldLastRow = Sheets("AllocatedAllFile").Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    lastDRS = oldLastRow - Sheets("genAllFile").Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1

    For j = 1 To 51
        newRowStart = 2
        For i = lastDRS + 1 To oldLastRow
             Sheets("AllocatedAllFile").Cells(i, j) = Sheets("test").Cells(newRowStart, j)
             newRowStart = newRowStart + 1
        Next i
    Next j
    
    
End Sub
```

I tried some forums for a quick fix but the suggestion was to define named ranges

Comment: On which line do you get the error? What are the values of _i_ and _j_ when the error occurs? Do the worksheets as mentioned in the code exist?

Comment: The error occurs on this line

Sheets("AllocatedAllFile").Cells(i, j) = Sheets("test").Cells(newRowStart, j)

all the sheets exist

I beleive the error occurs at i = 1151, j = 1

Comment: By the way, you can copy over arrays of values in a single line. No need to loop.  You can do `Sheets("AllocatedAllFile").Cells(lastDRS + 1, 1).Resize(oldLastRow - lastDRS, 51).Value = Sheets("test").Cells(newRowStart, 1).Resize(oldLastRow - lastDRS, 51).Value`

Comment: Could you share what it is supposed to do? `Alloc` has more rows than `Gen`. Shouldn't this difference be copied to `Test` (e.g. `Sheets("test").Cells(newRowStart, j).Value = Sheets("AllocatedAllFile").Cells(i, j).Value`) and not the other way around, from `Test` to `Alloc` (overwriting `Alloc`) as seen in the code? Or maybe should the data from `Test` be written to `Gen`? Think about the following: `Alloc.Copy Test` is (not quite) the 'same' as `Test.Value = Alloc.Value`. Note how the sides have switched. Please share your thoughts on it. Also, sharing some screenshots would do wonders.

Comment: So the tool is to do allocation of parts to suppliers and the test is a sheet which helps find duplicate rows and delete it, then the data is copied back to AllocatedAllFile. The Alloc file has some matched data so VBA is only checking duplicates of the unmatched data, that's why the alloc rows are more.

Comment: In the code, if `alr` (`oldLastRow`) is `10` and `glr` is `7` making `gfr = 8` then I would expect the code to loop **from 8 to 10**. But the code calculates `lastDRS = alr - gfr = 10 - 8 = 2` and then it loops the rows **from 2+1 To 10**. Maybe this is where the code goes wrong. Try to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Does `Sheets("test").Cells(newRowStart, j)` contain a broken formula?

If the cell contains a string like `"=SUM(A1/"`, trying to copy its value into another cell will cause Run-time error '1004'. This is because Excel trys to evaluate formulas placed into new cells, but the formula is incomplete and Excel fails to evaluate the formula. If you were typing this in manually, a tooltip would pop-up and ask you to fix the formula, but since it is an automated action with VBA, it just gives an error message.

You could avoid this error by telling the cells to treat new values as strings and not evaluate their formulas. Set the entire range to  `.NumberFormat = "@"` before you copy over all the values.